# Angular 5 .- Components property is not beeing updated??? why?

Tags: angular, service, components

So I have this progressLoaderComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { ProgressLoaderService } from './progress-loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progress-loader',
  templateUrl: './progress-loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progress-loader.component.scss']
})
export class ProgressLoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public prgLoaderSubscription: Subscription;

  // Loader Type
  public prgLoaderType;  

  constructor(private _pl: ProgressLoaderService) {
    this.prgLoaderType = 'spinner';
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.prgLoaderSubscription = this._pl.loaderSubject$.subscribe(data => {
      this.prgLoaderType = data.loaderType;
      console.log('**************************', this.prgLoaderType);
    });
  }

}
```

and the progressLoaderSerice:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Injectable()
export class ProgressLoaderService {

  private loaderSubject = new Subject<any>();
  public loaderSubject$ = this.loaderSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  setLoaderType(loaderType) {
    this.loaderSubject.next({loaderType: loaderType});
  }

}
```

from a other component I do call the `setLoaderType()` like:
    this._pl.setLoaderType('WTF!!!');

now the console.log() in the progressLoaderComponents onInit()-subscription does output `WTF!!!` but whatever I try, the property `prgLoaderType` is not beeing updated.. how can that be?

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz for this?

Comment: who call the `setLoaderType()` function?

Comment: @Luca .. a other component

Comment: can you post it too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your shared code, I created an angular project on stackblitz.

Take a look. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-51212347

I don't see anything wrong with your code. It should work the way it is, I didn't modify it. Check out `app.module.ts` to see if you got the imports right. Also in `app.component.ts` I'm calling your service every 1 second for 10 seconds, and as You can see the variable in your component is being set every time.